# Is there an out-of-the-box Report solution for Silverlight running Out-Of-Browser?

Tags: .net, silverlight, report

Is there an out-of-the-box Report solution for Silverlight running Out-Of-Browser?

The information I've found so far is unclear.  If not, what about a 3rd party that would support Silverlight OOB Reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've found, there is no out-of-the-box Report solution for Silverlight running Out-Of-Browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would try Stimulsoft reports. Their .NET solution was ahead of competition. 
The one for Silverlight is relatively new. It includes Silverlight report designer, embeddable in your app, as well as Silverlight report generator. Also, it's incredibly fast.

http://stimulsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

Stimulsoft Reports.Silverlight does support out-of-browser mode.